# I can't seem to tell why my code is failing here

Tags: java

I am trying to use files that contain long strings of numbers by inputing them as arguments. Then I am trying to find the hamming distance between the two strings. Right now I have errors on lines 7,8,9 and 11. They say "cannot find symbol: method length()." I am very new to java so I am wondering if I am using scanner incorrectly or I messed up somewhere else to cause these errors. Any insight would be appreciated.

If it helps the files I am importing are of the form:

```
 13413.123,
 12314.434,
 12353.809,
```

and so on

```
public static double calcDifference(String[] args) throws IOException {
       Scanner scanner = 
                new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
       Scanner scanner2 = 
                new Scanner(new File(args[1]));
       double a = 0;
       for (double x = 0; x < scanner.length(); x++) {
       for (double y = 0; y < scanner2.length(); y++) {
            if (scanner.charAt(x) == scanner2.charAt(y)) {
                a += 0;
            } else if (scanner.charAt(x) != scanner2.charAt(y)) {
                a += 1;
            }
        }
    }
return a;
}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation for `Scanner`?

Comment: Check the dcoumentation length in not a method Scanner class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: You could post the compiler error and which line is posing a problem

Comment: would recommend a `while` loop using the `hasNextLine()` as a test and `nextLine()` to actually get the next line as a `String`. then apply your difference loops on those strings

Comment: I suggest you let `x` and `y` be of type `int`, rather than `double`.  You're using them as integers, and doubles won't work in `charAt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scanner` doesn't have `length()` (or `chartAt()`, as Daemon points out).

If you want to read a whole file, the shortest way without using any external libraries (e.g. Apache) is:

```
String text = new Scanner(new File(args[0])).useDelimiter("$").next();
```

Also, good practice would be to close your files once you are done.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
String text = scanner.useDelimiter("$").next();
scanner.close();
```

Further clarification:

Now, you can use `length()` and `charAt()` on `text`. The $ is a regular expression symbol for end of input. So, the `Scanner` only stops at the end of input when `next()` is called. This isn't the only way to read a whole file, but it is the shortest.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, i would be looking at using text.length()? And what exactly is the "$"? Sorry if thats a stupid question.

Comment: I expanded my answer.